# Python truncating numbers from ODBC connection

Tags: python, odbc, ado

I have a production system that ran on Server 2003 that had to be rebuilt yesterday/today that talks to our AS400 (DB2).  The system is now Windows 7 x64.  It uses ADO objects to accomplish this, and the provider in the connection string is specified as MSDASQL, and it uses a system data source (dsn).  The problem is that numeric values are getting truncated.  Here's the cut down test version with its output as comments (The full script was written to cast Data.Fields().Value as float -- that doesn't help):

```
Con = win32com.client.Dispatch("ADODB.Connection")    
Con.Open ("Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=AS400", "UserID", "Password")
Data = win32com.client.Dispatch("ADODB.Recordset")
Data.Open("SelectStatement", Con, 2, 3, 1)
val = str(Data.Fields("FieldName").Value)
print val  #prints 53, value is 53.750 in the database

val2 = 123.123 + 1
print val2  #prints 124.123 as expected
```

I threw the val2 in at the end as a sanity check to make sure python wasn't treating all numerics wrongly.

I wrote a quick C# app that opens an ODBC connection and prints a numeric value.  It prints the correct value:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("selectstatement", new OdbcConnection("dsn=as400;uid=pwd;pwd=pwd"));
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                var val = dr["fieldname"];
                Console.WriteLine(val); //prints 53.750 as expected
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it doesn't appear to be a DSN misconfiguration since C# reads it right.  The vendor is at a lost as am I.  Does anyone have any ideas about where to look/what to try next?  I checked the ADO `Type` property and it prints 4, which means it KNOWS it's a single precision float, too.

Comment: As a hack/workaround, I can scale the value in the SQL statement then scale it back once I get it out, but the DB2 ODBC driver doesn't like `select val * 1000 as scaledval, * from table` but `select val * 1000 as scaledvale, other, fields, here from table` does work.  fml.  This script uses a LOT of columns from this table.

Comment: I am a fool when it comes to ado, but I know exactly the same happens if you use C++ and you do not set the `precision` and `decimal digits` properties when binding a column to some buffer. So, maybe you can find some additional property in all this ADO stuff to explicitly set decimal digits to 2. But as said, I never worked with ado, so this is really just guessing.